# Как при публикации веб-приложения перенести базу пользователей на сервер IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Есть созданное веб-приложение, которое работает правильно из под VS - регистрация и авторизация пользователей происходит без проблем. Приложение использует `ASP.NET Identity` для регистрации пользователей.

Это мое первое веб-приложение и я не знаю как правильно его **опубликовать**. Для начала я пытаюсь его опубликовать на локальном компьютере. Собственно приложение публикуется без проблем и работает правильно. Но при попытке ввода авторизации или регистрации нового пользователя появляется:

> При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с
>   сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен.
>   Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server
>   разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces,
>   error: 50 - Произошла ошибка Local Database Runtime.Невозможно создать
>   автоматический экземпляр. Дополнительные сведения об ошибке см. в
>   журнале событий приложений Windows.

Приложение опубликовано в `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\monit95`.
Начал изучать проблему и насколько мне удалось заметить база пользователей, которая храниться в проекте `...\App_Data\aspnet-WebApplication1-20150706062157.mdf` не перенеслась при публикации - по крайне мере я нигде не нашел файл `aspnet-WebApplication1-20150706062157.mdf`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю точно, но мне кажется этот файл тоже должен присутствовать.
Думаю приложение пытается получить доступ именно к этому файлу, ведь он указан в `Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20150706062157.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20150706062157;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Что делать? Как правильно опубликовать приложение? Может сам сервер `IIS` надо настраивать?

Answer (score 2):

База данных и не должна переноситься при публикации! Дело в том, что публикация приложения - процесс многократный, и перезаписывать уже существующую на сайте БД нельзя ни в коем случае. Вместо этого либо БД на сайте должна быть развернута сторонними средствами, либо приложение должно развернуть ее само (например, через механизм миграций Entity Framework).

В любом случае, приложение IIS не должно и не может (за редкими исключениями) использовать LocalDB. LocalDB - это БД только для разработчиков. Вам надо установить на сервер полноценную редакцию SQL Server (например, SQL Server Express) и заменить строку подключения через механизм параметров публикации.